# How to center a div inside a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with width of 1172px inherited from its parent. I have declared a div inside the row and I want to center align it. I tried applying `margin: 0 auto` and `text-align:center` which didn't work. How do I center it?

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="YelloBox" class="YelloBox"> 
    </div>                    
</div>
```

css:

```
.YelloBox {
    width: 515px;
    height: 602px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: var(--white);
    border: solid 1px #a28c77;
    border: solid 1px var(--reddish-grey);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display:table` in css

```css
.YelloBox {
    width: 515px;
    height: 602px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: var(--white);
    border: solid 1px #a28c77;
    border: solid 1px var(--reddish-grey);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: could you please give some info why it was not working for me so that I understand the concept. thank you

Comment: `text-align:center` used to align text elements.. Not a div element. If you give that to div element means that will align text inside the element

Comment: no I mean why `display:table worked` and not `marin: 0 auto`

Comment: These elements behave like  <table> HTML elements. It defines a block-level box. It must needs the margin:0 auto. To take the left right margin values for align content centered

Answer (score 1):

Just use `center-block` class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="YelloBox" class="YelloBox center-block"></div>
</div>
```

See details in [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

i think this is all you need to fully understand aligns. Take a good look and play with the demos cause they have pretty good and interactive ones.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Flex can also do same thing, **but read** the support page for a property because it might fail on some browsers.

http://caniuse.com/#search=flex